# How do i get the value (Number of Days) between 2 days

Tags: react-native

How do I get the number of Days between 2 dates? in React Native.
I have this code, does not seem to work as Expected , I am getting values cannot be cast from Doubles to String.

My Code Looks like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text , StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker'

export default class DifferenceDates extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       days : '',
       date1 : '',
       date2 : '',
    };
  }

  GetNumberofDays = () =>{
      //Alert.alert('Hi!')
      var origin_date = this.state.date1;
      var final_date = this.state.date2;
      var dateDiff = new Date(this.state.date1).getTime() - new Date(this.state.date2).getTime();
      var numofDays = Math.floor(dateDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      Alert.alert(numofDays);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DatePicker
        style={{width: 200}}
        date={this.state.date1}
        mode="date"
        placeholder="select date"
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        minDate="2021-01-31"
        maxDate="2032-12-31"
        confirmBtnText="Confirm"
        cancelBtnText="Cancel"
        customStyles={{
          dateIcon: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: 4,
            marginLeft: 0
          },
          dateInput: {
            marginLeft: 36
          }
          // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
        }}
        onDateChange={(date1) => {this.setState({date1: date1})}}
      />
    <DatePicker
        style={{width: 200}}
        date={this.state.date2}
        mode="date"
        placeholder="select date"
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        minDate="2021-01-31"
        maxDate="2032-12-31"
        confirmBtnText="Confirm"
        cancelBtnText="Cancel"
        customStyles={{
          dateIcon: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: 4,
            marginLeft: 0
          },
          dateInput: {
            marginLeft: 36
          }
          // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
        }}
        onDateChange={(date2) => {this.setState({date2: date2})}}
      />
      <Text>
          Days!
      </Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.GetNumberofDays();}} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.loginbtn}> Calculate Dates </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent :"center",
        alignItems:"center"
    },

    button:{
        marginTop:20,
        width:190,
        padding:15,
        borderRadius:5,
        backgroundColor:'#009999',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    loginbtn:{
        color:'#ffff'
    },

})
```

Sought the internet for more useful tips , I have not been able to come up with anything at this point. Please I do need help.

Comment: Have you logged your dates inside ```GetNumberofDays``` to make sure that those dates are being updated?

Answer (score 0):

```
numberOfDays = (from, to) => {
   const cFrom = new Date(from);
   const cTo = new Date(to);

   const timeFrom = cFrom.getTime();
   const timeTo = cTo.getTime();

   const timeStamp = timeTo - timeFrom;
   const days = timeStamp / ( 1000 * 3600 * 24 );

   return days;
}
```